# Changing the color of the ground in Alice?

Tags: alice

I'm super new to programming and taking my first class now. I'm trying to change the color of the moon in Alice 3.2 (so instead of a gray moon with craters I'd have a green moon with all the craters and everything). This seems like the kind of thing I should be able to do, but whenever I try to change the moon to green, it just gives me solid green instead of the green-with-craters I want. Is it possible to get the green-with-craters look?

I've tried looking up "How to change the ground color in Alice" and variations on Google with no help. I can change the color of the sky with no problem, so I don't know why I don't seem to be able to do it with the ground.

(Edit: My classmates don't seem to know either, and my prof isn't answering his email, which is why I'm hoping someone here can help.)

Comment: It is customary to include the code - indented- that you are using that is directly involved.  So people can evaluate what you have tried and make suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to just add a green color to the moon texture you are seeing using Alice. It is an image mapped over the moon object. So when you change to a green color it is replacing the image with a solid green.

You could take the existing moon image, put it into an image editor and work up a green version, then set your moon to use that new image map.